# Why is CSS3 PIE not working on sub pages when using absolute path in the CSS file?

Tags: html, css, css3pie

I have the following class:

```
a.greenbutton, input.greenbutton  {
    /*background: url("../image/button.png") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;*/
    behavior: url("/css3pie/PIE.php");
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 11px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 0;     
}
```

the PIE.php file is located in `/root/css3pie/`

You can take a look here:

http://trashtalk.dk/

and to see the difference:

http://trashtalk.dk/Apple/iPhone

you can even download the file from:

http://trashtalk.dk/css3pie/PIE.php

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not using an absolute path, you are using a relative path. To answer your question, I need to know where - in relation to your root folder - is your css file located.

Because...if it's , say, root/styles/ or whatever, then your pie rule needs two dots '..' before the /csspie stuff.

In other words, instead of:

```
behavior: url("/css3pie/PIE.php");
```

you need:

```
behavior: url("../css3pie/PIE.php");
```

but this is just guess work, I need to know where your css file/folder is located first.

Ok, refer to this page:

http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/

> The behavior URL
>
> IE interprets the URL for the behavior property relative to the source
>   HTML document, rather than relative to the CSS file like every other
>   CSS property. This makes invoking the PIE behavior inconvenient,
>   because the URL has to either be:
>
> Absolute from the domain root — this makes the CSS not easily moveable
>   between directories — or, Relative to the HTML document — this makes
>   the CSS not easily reusable between different HTML files. URLs in
>   PIE-interpreted CSS properties
>
> PIE does not parse the CSS stylesheets (to do so would be unacceptably
>   slow); it lets IE handle the parsing, selector querying, cascading,
>   etc. and then simply asks it for the resulting property values. This
>   means that when PIE gets a property value, it has no knowledge of the
>   context from which that value originated.
>
> As a result, for properties which contain URL values (such as
>   border-image or -pie-background), PIE cannot resolve those URLs
>   relative to the CSS file in which they appear. It resolves them
>   instead relative to the JavaScript execution context, which is the
>   location of the source HTML document.

Cheers
G

UPDATE:

Make sure you have methodically tried, one by one, all of these:

1. behavior: url("../css3pie/PIE.php");
2. behavior: url("/../css3pie/PIE.php");
3. **behavior: url("http://trashtalk.dk/css3pie/PIE.php");**

UHMMM...where is the css3 pie rule in your css? I don't see it, you know, something like -pie-background or whatever.

Comment: Hi
The stylesheet is located here:
/public_html/catalog/view/theme/vasco/stylesheet
where public_html is the root folder. Ander the css3pie folder is located in /public_html/css3pie/

Comment: i tried putting the css3pie folder in the same folder as the stylesheet, but i didnt work either

Comment: i added a link and explanation, see my original post above

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem still remains unresolved though. What should the absolute path look like? The directories are in my comments above

Comment: try this: behavior: url("css3pie/PIE.php");

Comment: I tried that one too. You can check the source code. Could there perhaps be something "wrong" with my server, that is causing the issue? I have read that putting a leading slash in front of the path makes it go from the root directory. So i would assume the answer is "/css3pie/PIE.PHP" - but this "absolute" path aint working :S

Comment: kenci, did you see the absolute alternative i posted at the bottom of my original post?

Comment: Sorry for my slow response. I have tried all your suggestions, and none of them seem to work. Could my server somehow be causing this?

Comment: there is something i forgot about, please see the very end of my original post above

Comment: Again, sorry for my slow answer. I have been very busy lately. The css pie rule is in the CSS class show above: behavior: url("/css3pie/PIE.php");

Comment: that is not the css pie rule, that is just the call to pie itself, the pie rule is -pie-something

Comment: I thought that including the pie file was enough, and it would know how to make the borders rounded itself?

Comment: my bad, the border-radius property does not require the -pie- prefix, that was for background gradient. Did you try the direct link suggestion I posted? behavior: url("http://trashtalk.dk/css3pie/PIE.php");

Comment: Yes i have tried this as well. I will just have to give up on PIE. Are there any other solutions to get rounded borders in IE 6-8 ?

Comment: yeah, using images. I dont like PIE because overlapping effects make it crash (for example, shadows + borders + gradients). For crap browsers (all of IE) I just use conditional statements and images because the time that goes into cross-browser optimization is just not worth it